# Exception: when trying to use Enumerable.Any Method with Mobile Services query

Tags: linq, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, query-expressions, notsupportedexception

I have a mobile app build with Xamarin Forms and I'm using [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync), [to enable offline sync in my mobile application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data)

so,
I have two tables

- PurchaseOrders
- PurcahseOrderDetails

  ```
  public IMobileServiceSyncTable<PurchaseOrders> PurchaseOrdersTable;
  public IMobileServiceSyncTable<PurchaseOrderDetails> PurchaseOrderDetailsTable;
  ```

and I want to sync the records in the **PurchaseOrders** Table based on **UserId**

and then sync  the records in  **PurchaseOrderDetails** Table based on **Id of PurcahseOrder**

To do that I'm trying this

**Get Purchase Orders based on User Id**

```
var purchaseOrders = (await GetAllPurchaseOrdersAsync(syncFromServer:true, userId)).ToList();

// in sync method 
await PurchaseOrdersTable.PullAsync(queryName, PurchaseOrdersTable.CreateQuery().Where(w => w.Userid == userId));
```

**When I'm trying to get Purchase Order Details based on Id in the list of PurchaseOrders**

```
await PurchaseOrderDetailsTable.PullAsync(queryName,
                         PurchaseOrderDetailsTable.CreateQuery().Where(pod => purchaseOrders.Any(po => po.Id == pod.PoId)));
```

I get the exception below

> 'value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectName.Models.PurchaseOrder]).Any(po => (po.Id == pod.PoId))' is not supported in a 'Where' Mobile Services query expression.

**Can I get an explanation about the error above and how to solve it?**

Comment: How is the relationship between `PurchaseOrder` and `PurchaseOrderDetail` defined?

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT Thanks for your reply, I'm working on an old project which doesn't contain a relationship between `PurchaseOrders` and  `PurchaseOrderDetails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mobile data is backed by table service, then Any is not a supported LINQ operator (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service) so that might be source of the exception.

Since `PurchaseOrder` doesn't contain a collection of `PurchaseOrderDetail`, one workaround I can think of is to iterate on `purchaseOrders` and select from `purchaseOrderDetails`.

```
var poDetails = new List<PurchaseOrderDetail>();
foreach (var po in purchaseOrders)
{
   var poDetail = await PurchaseOrderDetails.PullAsync(queryName, PurchaseOrderDetailsTable.CreateQuery().Where(pod => po.Id == pod.PoId);
   poDetails.Add(poDetail);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I also solved it by the same way